# Neo4j, Cypher: Removing direction on query changes results, but relationship only has one direction.

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am using Neo4j + Cypher to build a content recommendation engine. I am using Neo4j 2.1.2 enterprise

I have imported data representing users who have visited pages. The only relationship on my graph is (user)-[:VIEWED]->(page). The following query is intended to display the page identifier pid (a unique property) of each page which other users also viewed, and how many times all those users viewed that page. So, for a given page, I want to see which other pages users viewed, and how many users viewed each page.

```
MATCH (p:Page)<--(u:User)-->(p2:Page) 
WHERE (p.pid=501515) 
RETURN p.pid, p2.pid, count(u) 
ORDER BY count(u) desc 
LIMIT 3
```

This returns no results. However, if I simply remove the direction, I get three results as expected.

```
MATCH (p:Page)--(u:User)--(p2:Page) 
WHERE (p.pid=501515) 
RETURN p.pid, p2.pid, count(u) 
ORDER BY count(u) desc 
LIMIT 3
```

This returns the values I expect. (I can verify the data with other queries).

Why do the results of these queries differ?

Comment: Are you sure your model is `(user)-[:VIEWED]->(page)`? Your first query is working for me. See: http://console.neo4j.org/r/39rnzq

Comment: Thanks for the help. Yes, I can confirm that model. I'm trying to get data from different users. So, find all users who have viewed this page, find all the pages they have also viewed, then count the total number of users who have viewed each of those page. The order by and limit clauses work correctly. But, sometimes I don't get any data returned, even when I know other users have viewed the page.

Comment: As a sanity check, does this query return any results?

`MATCH (p:Page)-->(u:User) RETURN p, r;`

Comment: Nope. "r not defined (line 1, column 37)"

Comment: I replaced the 'r' with 'u' and the query ran but returned no results.  The relationship is the other way around, I believe.

Comment: `MATCH (p:Page)<--(u:User) RETURN p, u limit 10;`
This returns results.

Comment: Why you are matching page node twice MATCH (p:Page)--(u:User)--(p2:Page)? I think (p:Page)--(u:User) it will give you what you need.

Confirm if i misunderstood the problem .

Comment: I'm matching page node twice because for a given node, I want to return other nodes that visitors also viewed. The count is to order them by most viewed. I've found a way to get this data with a different query. To stick to the original question, I'm still wondering why the direction in my query is altering the results.